# Произношение "-чн-"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как все-таки правильно произносить суффикс "-чн-": так, как есть, или как "-шн-"? То есть: "булочная" или "булоШная" и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В мужском роде всегда произносится "-чн": *срочный, строчный* и т. д.
В женских отчествах — "-шн-": *КузьминиШна*, а также в словах: *сквореШник, конеШно, пустяШный, горчиШный*.
А бывает, что можно произносить и так, и так: *булочная — булоШная, порядочный — порядоШный* и т. д.
Но не стоит забывать, что даже если читается "-шн-", пишется все равно "-чн-".